# how i can order flat array by parent id in php

Tags: php, arrays, tree

i have bellow array it show parent and childs order but i need to order by parent

```
$input = array(
    array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'parent_id ' => null
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 2,
        'parent_id ' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 3,
        'parent_id ' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 4,
        'parent_id ' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 5,
        'parent_id ' => 2
    )   
);
```

i use same way to sort with parent but have same error

```
function cmp($a, $b) {    
    if ($a['parent_id'] == $b['parent_id']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['parent_id'] < $b['parent_id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($data, 'cmp');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

i need to return like this

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 3
    )   
);
```

if you can help me in mysql better than php

```
CREATE TABLE cars
    (`id` int, `parent_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO cars
    (`id`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 5),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 2)
;



SELECT
id
FROM
  cars
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END,
  parent_id,
  id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f11dc2/1

Comment: well - the array indizes in your original array are called `PARENT`, not `parent_id` - see anything *mismatched*?

Comment: The MySQL comment in the last sentence looks out of place. Where is your MySQL related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of solutions around on SOF, so I tried a few ( hint ) and I came up with this...

```
usort($input, function($a,$b){ return $a['ID']-$b['PARENT'];} );
var_dump($input);
```

That gives you what you are after.

**UPDATE:**
Ok this was bugging me... so I have come up with this. Give it a shot!

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.parent_id FROM cars c1
LEFT JOIN cars c2 ON c2.id = c1.parent_id
GROUP BY c2.parent_id
```

You will have to play with this and test it.

Comment: this better than but you sure work correctly in large data ?

Comment: please help , use a faster way .

Comment: The reason you are having so much trouble is due to your case of  id < parent_id. How can an id have a parent_id that is greater than an existing id? So what are your reasons for this? Case in point id=3, parent_id = 5... That's what is blowing things up.

Comment: Unfortunately we have unsorted parent id , this my problem , child id dont have parent , then we must order array by parent.

Comment: i tested this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40635263/6477873 but have error in large data

Answer (score 0):

> First, it seems like you have an Empty Space after the **_id** in the `parent_id` Key. Anyways, `usort()` is the shortest way to perform the sorting you intend like so:

**GIVEN ARRAY:**

```
<?php

    $input = array(
        array(
            'ID' => 1,
            'parent_id' => null
        ),
        array(
            'ID' => 2,
            'parent_id' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'ID' => 3,
            'parent_id' => 5
        ),
        array(
            'ID' => 4,
            'parent_id' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'ID' => 5,
            'parent_id' => 2
        )
    );
```

> **ALGORITM:**

```
<?php

    usort($input,
            function($prev, $next){
                return $prev['parent_id']> $next['parent_id'];
            }
    );
    var_dump($input);
```

> **RESULT OF THE DUMP ABOVE:**

```
    array (size=5)
      0 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 1
          'parent_id' => null
      1 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 2
          'parent_id' => int 1
      2 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 5
          'parent_id' => int 2
      3 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 4
          'parent_id' => int 3
      4 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 3
          'parent_id' => int 5
```

> If you prefer a very long, quirk, strange, convoluted and tedious work-around, this function might help. [Quick Test.](https://eval.in/678912)

```
<?php

    function orderByPID($arrInput, $direction='asc'){
        $arrSorted      = [];
        $arrPID         = [];
        foreach($arrInput as $iKey=>$subArray){
            $pid        = ($subArray['parent_id']==null) ? 0 : $subArray['parent_id'];
            $arrPID[]   = $pid;
        }
        $flipped        = array_flip($arrPID);
        if($direction == 'asc'){
            ksort($flipped);
        }else{
            krsort($flipped);
        }

        foreach($flipped as $pid=>$index){
            $pid            = ($pid == '') ? null : $pid;
            foreach($arrInput as $iKey=>$subArray){
                if($subArray['parent_id'] == $pid){
                    $arrSorted[]    = $subArray;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $arrSorted;
    }

    var_dump( orderByPID($input) );
```

> **RESULT OF VAR_DUMP:**

```
    array (size=5)
      0 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 1
          'parent_id' => null
      1 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 2
          'parent_id' => int 1
      2 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 5
          'parent_id' => int 2
      3 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 4
          'parent_id' => int 3
      4 =>
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => int 3
          'parent_id' => int 5
```

Comment: it work but is like my code , it must return 1,2,5,3,4 ----- but your code return 1,2,5,4,3

Comment: @VahidAlvandi  How do do mean  **1,2,5,3,4**?. Test it out yourself here https://eval.in/678929 it sure return **1,2,5,4,3** -- *if by that you meant the IDs*

Comment: because 3 is parent 4

Comment: this answer by @TimBrownlaw  work ok , but is slow , please help me to use a way with fast speed  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40635263/6477873